# How do I pass content of a text file as a url parameter

Tags: php

I want to pass the content of a text file to a url. So I use the fgets function to read the content of the file line by line and store it in a string and then pass it to the url in question. But for some reason,it does not work . How do I do this or pass the content of a text file as a parameter in a url .

```
$handle= fopen("/path/to/file/filename.txt","r");
while(($line=fgets($handle))!==false) {        
    $msisdn=str_replace("\n", " ", $line);
}
$send="http://127.0.0.1:13014/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar&text=text&from=shortcode&to=$msisdn&smsc=smsc";
fclose($handle);

   $curl=curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$send);
   curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $result=curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl)
```

Edit : I am able to pass the contents of the file(which is a list of numbers) to the string "$msisdn"  but an echo of the url shows it only picks one number. How do I get to pass all content of the file to url.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Can you be more specific...?

Comment: `&from=$shortcode.&to` the .(dot) can not be a good thing when it comes to URL. If you are sending a lot of information GET is not the best solution. You also need to url_encode your variable content

Answer (score 0):

```
$handle= fopen("/path/to/file/filename.txt","r");
  while(($line=fgets($handle))!==false){        
     $msisdn=str_replace("\n", " ", $line);
  }
$send="http://127.0.0.1:13014/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar&text=text&from=$shortcode.&to=$msisdn&smsc=smsc";
fclose($handle);

header('Location: '.$send);
```

Comment: I see now in your $send variable you have a point after $shortcode ... Why ?

Answer (score 0):

**1st** : never transfer confidential data in URL => security problem
**2nd** : always verify the returned value of your functions => you have no guarantee that the file was successfully opened
**3rd** : what's the structure of your file ? should we guess ?
**4th** : try to have a better implementation, with something like this

```
$params = array ('username' => $username,
                 'text'     => $text);
$preparedParams = array();
foreach($params as $paramKey => $paramValue) {
   // do control if $paramValue is valid ... log error .. throw something
   $preparedParams[] = $paramKey . '=' . $paramValue ;
}
$urlParams = explode ('&', $preparedParams);
header('Location: ' . YOUR_SERVER:PORT/YOUR_CONTROLLER/ . $urlParams;
```

My advice is tu use [PHP CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead of `header('Location: ')`